# Receiving error message "The type "XmlNode" is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.", but appropriate assembly is referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, system.xml

I've been searching for solution for a long time with no luck. I'm using this code to extract text from a .odt file:

```
public String ReadOdt(String path)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var doc = new TextDocument())
            {
                doc.Load(path);

                XElement stylesPart = XElement.Parse(doc.DocumentStyles.Styles.OuterXml);
                string stylesText = string.Join("\r\n", stylesPart.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "header" || x.Name.LocalName == "footer").Select(y => y.Value));

                var mainPart = doc.Content.Cast<IContent>();
                var mainText = String.Join("\r\n", mainPart.Select(x => x.Node.InnerText));

                sb.Append(stylesText + "\r\n");
                sb.Append(mainText);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

However, Visual Studio is telling me:

> Error CS0012: The type 'XmlNode' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. (CS0012) (ScriptTablerV0)

And the same thing for type 'XmlDocument'.

As a solution it proposes to import the System.Xml reference, but this doesn't change anything and the errors persist.

Is there anything i should look at or try? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've tried using other methods/classes from the System.Xml assembly and they've worked with no problems, but VS still doesn't recognise Styles and Node.

Comment: Check if the xml is valid.  You can use the Visual Studio Menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then past the xml into the view.  Error will show like any compiler error in the Error List.

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure i understand what you mean by paste the xml into the view, but i tried some other things from the System.Xml assembly like declaring an XmlDocument, which worked. I'm also using System.Xml.Linq in the same script with no issues.

Comment: I mean open the file with notepad and past the code into the window.  Actually paste the results from  doc.DocumentStyles.Styles.OuterXml .

Comment: It seems to me that one of the assemblies you are referencing (What is script tabler= V0?) is referencing (specific version) a version of System.Xml (System.Xml, Version=1.0.5000.0). Can you please refer to this link? It may help to solve your problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: @OguzOzgul ScriptTabler is just the name of the project. So i have System.Xml Version=2.0.5.0 referenced. Are you suggesting i try to force it to use System.Xml Version=1.0.5.0?

Comment: @jdweng Sorry i'm still not sure what you mean, there's no xml file. The goal is to read xml from an odt document, but there's no result from doc.DocumentStyles.Styles.OuterXml. Nothing will run because it doesn't acknowledge the System.Xml assembly i have referenced.

Comment: No, I am suggesting to force the framework to redirect System.Xml version 1.0.5000 references (I don't know who references that specific - old version) to a higher version, actually, to the version you are referencing.

Comment: It is still xml even tough it is not coming from a file and the format has to meet the xml specification.